# mysql update query to set field with id's of another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables in database

**1) videos.**

```
id    name
1     one
2     two
3     three
```

**2) session_has_video.**

```
session_id    video_id
1             1
1             3
```

**3) channel_has_session.**

```
channel_id    session_id    videos
1             1
```

I want to update `channel_has_session.videos` with all the `video.id` where `video.id` is in `session.session_id`. It means it should be `1,3`

So, updated table should look like this

**channel_has_session.**

```
channel_id    session_id    videos
1             1             1,3
```

i tried this query, but obvious not working.

```
update channel_has_session set videos = ( SELECT video_id FROM session_has_video where session_id=1 ) where session_id=1 and channel_id=1
```

Is there any easiest way to do like this in MySQL?

Comment: I don't see the `drills` column mentioned anywhere in your problem.  I will also say that you should avoid using comma-separated values in your table, which renders your database non-relational (a bad thing usually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the `channel_has_session` table to a temporary table containing each `session_id` along with its comma-separated list of `video_id` values.  Then do a `SET` on the `channel_has_session` table using this CSV list.  Try this query:

```
UPDATE
    channel_has_session AS ch
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT session_id, GROUP_CONCAT(video_id) AS videos
        FROM session_has_video
        GROUP BY session_id
    ) AS t on ch.session_id = t.session_id
SET ch.videos = t.videos
WHERE ch.channel_id = 1 AND ch.session_id = 1
```

Comment: yes its working for me, is there any way to update only specific record like `where channel_id=1 and session_id=1` ?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve it would be by using the `group_concat()` function, as:

```
UPDATE channel_has_session
SET videos = (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT video_id SEPARATOR ',')
    FROM session_has_video
    WHERE session_id = 1
)
WHERE session_id = 1 AND channel_id = 1
```

But, as said, using comma-separated values in your database is discouraged.