# MySQL query, record not selecting proper with IN clause

Tags: php, mysql

here i have 2 table in database like this,

**1)videos**

```
id        name   
200119    one
200120    two
200121    three
```

**2)sessions_to_channels**

```
channel_id    playlist_id   videos
50            359           200119,200120,200121
```

I want to select all the `videos.name` from `videos` table where `videos.id IN sessions_to_channels.videos`.

For that i am using this query,

```
SELECT v.name FROM videos as v WHERE v.id in ( select videos from sessions_to_channels where playlist_id=359 and channel_id=50 )
```

But it return me only 1 record

```
id      name
200119  one
```

I am doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Instead of executing the query, try and echo it and see if the syntax is correct.

Comment: @Epodax only issue is, it returns only 1 record. when i put sub-query result into IN clause, then it return me correct result

Comment: Then I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: Your query isn't going to work as is, because you are trying to find a value in a comma-separated string.  In your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450126/mysql-update-query-to-set-field-with-ids-of-another-table/32450385#32450385) today, you were advised to not use this database design.  Now the roosters are coming home to roost.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you are right, but this database designed by other. i have only option to use it any how

Comment: If you absolutely have to use comma separated values in a database column, then look at [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).... though it's still bad database design, and will never be an efficient query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use string in sessions_to_channels.videos, you must use FIND_IN_SET.
Like

```
SELECT v.name
FROM videos AS v
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(v.id, (
    SELECT videos FROM sessions_to_channels WHERE playlist_id=359 and channel_id=50 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving comma-separated data is never a good choice and the best option is to normalize the table. This will definitely make your life easy, however for the current situation you can use `find_in_set` function something as

```
SELECT v.name
FROM videos v JOIN sessions_to_channels s
ON FIND_IN_SET(v.id,s.videos) > 0 
WHERE s.playlist_id = 359 AND s.channel_id = 50;
```